# R, Cramer V and alternatives

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand Cramer V and if it fits my data (after CHI squared returns a significant association between variables) and also looking for alternatives (I've heard a Spearman correlation might be better in some cases..?)

1st example: I have a yes/no response from users and there are 2 conditions (2x2 matrix)

```
library(rcompanion)
x <- matrix(c(144,120,66,90), nrow = 2)
colnames(x) <- c("No", "Yes")
rownames(x) <- c("Cond1", "Cond2")
cramerV(x, conf = 95)
```

2nd example: similar but the options for the answers are 3 (so a 3x2 matrix).

```
library(rcompanion)
x <- matrix(c(57,27,87,93,66,90), nrow = 2)
colnames(x) <- c("NA", "No", "Yes")
rownames(x) <- c("Cond1", "Cond2")
cramerV(x, conf = 95)
```

is this the correct implementation of the Cramer V? I'm struggling to understand what the p-value is actually telling me. how does a single p-value represent how strong is the association between all those values? are there better alternatives? thanks

Comment: Acccording to `?cramerV`, it says `x - Either a two-way table or a two-way matrix`

Comment: From my understanding, it is only taking the first two columns in the second case `cramerV(x[, 1:2], conf = 95)` returns the same values as `x`, whereas `cramerV(x[, 2:3], conf = 95)` returns different

Comment: The package `DescTools` has many different measures of association between pairs of variables depending on whether they are categorical, rank, or ratio. You probably should take this question to CrossValidated since it is more about statistics than about R.

Comment: @akrun I do get different results. cramerV(x, conf = 95) = 0.1865, cramerV(x[, 2:3], conf = 95) = 0.06034, cramerV(x[, 1:2], conf = 95) = 0.1826

Comment: It sounds like there is some confusion in these comments.  Cramer's V, like a chi-square test of association, takes into account the entire (2-way) table.  Some alternative functions can be called from the following code.  Some of these allow for determination of confidence intervals. `x <- matrix(c(57,27,87,93,66,90), nrow = 2); library(rcompanion); cramerV(x); library(rcompanion); cramerV(x); library(DescTools); CramerV(x); library(vcd); assocstats(x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**General information:**

1. **Cramer's V** gives us information about the statistical relationship between **two or more** **nominally scaled variables** (e.g. eye color: green, blue, brown)
2. When determining **Cramer's V**, the chi-square value (X²) is standardized. This enables us to compare relationships between variables using Cramer’s V. (Similar to Pearson contingency coefficient that is also a standardized measure of correlation based on chi-square (X²).

**Your example 1:**
Here we want to assess the association of condition(`cond1`/`cond2`) and answer (`yes`/`no`)

We need the chi-square value to calculate Cramer’s V, therefore
we first determine chi-square value and then convert into a value for Cramer’s V.

We get  Cramer V `0.1183`

**Interpretation:**
Cramer's V is always between 0 and 1.
0 means no association
1 means complete/very strong association

**Rule of thumb**:
Cramer's V

- 0 - 0.2 -> weak association
- 0.2 - 0.6 -> middle association
- 0.6 - 1 -> strong association

**In this example with a Cramer V of 0.12 there is a weak association between condition and answer.**

**Note:**
As we use nominal scaled variables we can assess the strength of the association but **not the direction**!

**Same interpretation for example 2.**
It does not matter how many nominal scaled variables you assess.
The association here is 0.19 -> weak.

**In your examples you can use Carmer's V to assess the strength of association.**

Comment: thanks can you expand the Note about not assessing the direction? Could it be useful to do that with my data and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: The direction of the association is always symbolized by a sign either positive (+) or negative (-). In this case you would need a regression analysis. Here you can assess the correlations coefficient with positive direction or negative direction. Imagine a scatterplot with a pattern of all data points , and regress them to a line. This line will give you the direction.